# Authenticate users against AWS cognito with Vue3 amplify

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and have set up an AWS user pool (amazoncognito.com).
The goal is to authenticate users with a username and password against Cognito and receive the OAuth2 token to authenticate API requests made against the AWS API gateway.

**Challenge:**
It seems that AWS amplify is not working with the latest vue3 release. It only shows me that the user is not logged in but not displaying any login or logout buttons -regardless of the configuration.

**Potential solutions I am interested in (order of preference)**

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
      identityPoolId: 'eu-central-1_REST-OF-ID',
      region: 'eu-central-1',
      userPoolWebClientId: '4t49u0pu0skkREST-OF-ID',
      mandatorySignIn: false,
      cookieStorage: {
            domain: 'PREFIX.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',
            path: '/',
            expires: 365,
            sameSite: "lax",
            secure: true
        },
      authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
      oauth: {
          domain: 'PREFIX.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',
          scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
          redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
      }
  }
});

import { createStore } from 'vuex'
const store = createStore({
    state() {
      return {
        entries: []
      };
    },
    mutations: {
      addTime(state, item) {
        state.entries.push(item);
      }
    }
});

createApp(App).use(store, Amplify, Auth).mount("#app");
```

And inside App.vue

```
  <template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <AddTime/>
  <amplify-authenticator>
    <div>
    Inside Authenticator
    <amplify-sign-in></amplify-sign-in>
      <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
    </div>
  </amplify-authenticator>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import AddTime from './components/AddTime.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    AddTime,
  }
}
</script>
```

1. Has anyone being able to just use the AWS amplify authentication module with vue3?
2. How can I access the Cognito OAuth 2.0 authorization server with vue3 and fetch (Authenticating and receiving the token, by posting the credentials a user placed?

Comment: Have you tried Amplify CLI? That way you don't have to worry about content of Amplify config (`aws-exports.js`) and it may be working with Vue3
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli

Comment: Hey, the issue is that even the components are not showing. Regardless of the configuration. No Login-Button no nothing. I followed https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource

Comment: I see. Did you catch any errors? May be have a try/catch around `createApp(App).use(Amplify, Auth).mount("#app");` and catch some errors thrown?

Comment: No errors :( The app is rendering, showing the vue default app and an "Inside Authenticator" but nothing else, no login- no logout. In my earlier tries, last year with vue2 (using the cli) all was working.

Answer (score 1):

Vue3 is now supported by Amplify, but it's still in the early phases. The big change is that you no longer use the ui-vue package. You need to use ui-components:

`yarn add aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-components`

[AWS has an auth example for you to use on their website.](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue) Make sure you select the Vue3 tabs in the example. I can also confirm that this has worked for me within ionic apps too.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, vue3 is just not supported even months after the release.
See: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6756